# CKEditor: Is there a method to do escape character job?

Tags: mongodb, ckeditor, html-escape-characters

The content output by the editor is with html tag,

but I want store them into the `Mongodb`, so I think I need to do a escape character job,

Is the ckeditor own escape character method?

BTW, is it necessary to do escape character job? Or I better convert them to other data format?

Answer (score 0):

Native JS methods will solve your problem:

```
escape( '<a href="#">Foo</a>' )
> %3Ca%20href%3D%22%23%22%3EFoo%3C/a%3E

unescape( '%3Ca%20href%3D%22%23%22%3EFoo%3C/a%3E' )
> <a href="#">Foo</a>
```